# Are there expert system shells for the mac?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, expert-system

Recently I had an interesting AI discussion with a friend, and I became curious about expert systems.

After spending 2 hours on Google I couldn't find anything useful to get started with. Does anyone know an expert system shell which runs on the mac and is documented well enough so a beginner can comprehend and use it to build an expert system?

I think playing with them is a good way to learn how they work, how the knowledge is modeled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CLIPS runs with Mac OS X: http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/. There's online documentation available as well as PDFs. You can glance through the User's Guide to see if it's something of interest to you.